# General question regarding customer/data_request webhooks

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have designed a app. I have questions regarding customer/data_request webhooks

In what format does Shopify expect app developers to respond to these webhooks?

Should our response be sent back to the merchant's email (even though the customer requested this data)?

Comment: Shopify expects a **200 success** response to the webhooks. I don't understand why you want to send the response to the merchant's email?

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas , I ask about shopify mandatory webhook. when merchant clicks "View Customer Data" . It calls the madatory webhook ("Customer data request") endpoint . I understand "customer data erasure" and "shop data erasure" . I have a doubt how to handle "Customer data request"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the Shopify documentation when a customer requests their data from a store owner, Shopify sends a payload on the **customers/data_request** topic to the apps installed on that store. If your app has been granted access to customers or orders, then you receive a data request webhook with the resource IDs of the data that you need to provide to the store owner. It's your responsibility to provide this data to the store owner directly.

This means you need to send the data to the merchant/store owner which the merchant needs to process and send the details to the customer. Alternatively, you can create a template and send the details directly to the customer on behalf of the Merchant.

You need to respond back to this webhook with a 200 success response.

Documentation: [Link](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/gdpr-resources#customers-data_request)

Comment: One more doubt i got UserTokenDetails:{ "No Access"} as response for data request while i place end point url in my app setup page.

Comment: As well as, can you please send the response format for what u mentioned "send the data to the merchant/store owner which the merchant needs to process and send the details to the customer"

Comment: You got  UserTokenDetails:{ "No Access"} error while saving the webhook? The response format is present in the documentation link. You can forward the same to merchant's endpoint.

Comment: No . It happens at the time webhook call.. (Merchants clicks "Request Customer Data" Button)

Comment: Does your app have access to customer data or order data? Maybe you need to check the permissions provided to your app.

Comment: Yes my app have a permission to access customer and orders . my app have a permission to " Read orders, transactions, and fulfillments" ,"Read customer details and customer groups","Read all orders"
This app has access to personal information such as: Customer names, e-mail addresses, phone numbers, physical addresses, geolocations, IP addresses, and browser user agents

Comment: Then it should work perfectly. The webhook works perfectly for me. Try reinstalling the app.

Comment: But it is not working for me . still i got "userTokenDetails [ 'NoAccess' ]" in req parameter . I have all permissions . My webhook is also triggered. Inside the function req parameter i got "userTokenDetails [ 'NoAccess' ]"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187927/discussion-between-subhrajyoti-das-and-sammu-sundar).